# Ensemble average of product of spin operators?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, operators, quantum-spin

How do you evaluate the canonical ensemble average of a product of spins, e.g.:

$$[S_zS_x]$$

Where:

$$S_x = \frac{\hbar}{2}
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & 1\\
  1 & 0\\
 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$S_y = \frac{\hbar}{2}
 \begin{pmatrix}
  0 & -i\\
  i & 0\\
 \end{pmatrix}$$
$$S_z = \frac{\hbar}{2}
 \begin{pmatrix}
  1 & 0\\
  0 & -1\\
 \end{pmatrix}$$

The matrices are too simple, but then how is the ensemble average of the resultant matrix defined? EDIT: I knew it is about the density matrix, but I guess I was confuseing this with something else. Thanks anyway.

Comment: Do you have the hamiltonian?

Comment: Hamiltonian is just Ising model: $$H = A\sum_{i=1}^N S_i^zS_{i+1}^z$$, A is constant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The term *canonical* gives it away.

The canonical ensemble density matrix $\rho$ is defined as follows in terms of the Hamiltonian $H$ and inverse temperature $\beta = 1/kT$:
\begin{align}
  \rho(\beta) = \frac{1}{Z(\beta)}e^{-\beta H}, \qquad Z(\beta) = \mathrm{tr}(e^{-\beta H})
\end{align}
Then the canonical ensemble average of any observable $O$ is given by
\begin{align}
  \langle O\rangle = \mathrm{tr}(\rho\, O).
\end{align}
In your case, simply use $H = H_{\mathrm{Ising}}$ and $O = S_zS_x$.

Comment: Also, do I need to diagonalize the Hamiltonian first before plugging in these equations?

Comment: @student1 I haven't done the computation myself.  You do not *need* to diagonalize the Hamiltonian although that will probably make it significantly easier to compute the density matrix unless perhaps you're using a computer algebra system.